# after changed .jsf extention couldnt run the project

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, file-extension

earlier when we save.xhtml it had run the project but now when we change .jsf it is not run the project.. there is error in 404

here my code:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web    Application 2.3//EN"  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
 -->
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"      xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>sms</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>/pages/xhtml/login.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
      <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
      <param-value>ui-lightness</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

            </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
      <listener- class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter- class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
      <!-- mandatory to allow the managed bean to forward the request to the filter -->
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
      <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
      <param-value>commons</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
      <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
      <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
      <param- name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param- name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.faces.writeStateAtFormEnd</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>
      org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
            </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
      <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      < servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
      <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <error-page>
      <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
      <location>/pages/xhtml/sessionExpired.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <session-config>
      <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
  </web-app>
```

login.jsf

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"              "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui">
   <h:head>
     <title></title>

     </h:head>

    <h:body>
  <h:form>

    <h:outputText  value="Welcome " style="color:#BB7104;font-size:20px;">           </h:outputText><h:outputText value="Please Login"></h:outputText>
                                <br></br>
                            <h:message for="formLogin" style="color:red">                </h:message>


     <table style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            <tr><td>
                            <b:inputText id="uName" value="#{loginMB.loginaccess.username}" >

                             <f:facet name="prepend">
                              <b:iconAwesome name="fa fa-user" />
                             </f:facet>
                            </b:inputText>
                            <p:watermark value="UserName" for="uName"></p:watermark>
                            <h:message for="uName" style="color:red;font-size:11px;" id="un"></h:message>
                            </td></tr>
                            <tr><td>
                            <b:inputSecret id="pwd" value="#{loginMB.loginaccess.userpassword}"   placeholder="Password"> 

                             <f:facet name="prepend">
                            <b:iconAwesome name="fa fa-key" />
                             </f:facet>
                            </b:inputSecret>
                            <h:message for="pwd" id="pd" style="color:red;font-size:11px;"></h:message>
                            </td></tr>
                            </table>
                            </h:form>

                            <table>
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                            <b:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginMB.userLogin}" look="warning"  iconAwesome="sign-in"></b:commandButton>
                            </td></tr></table>




       </ui:composition>
```

please give me any suggestion

Comment: Your login file should still have the .xtrml file extension. The .jsf is only the for the servlet mapping. So you are saving the file as foo.hxhtml but in the browser you are requesting the file under the URL foo.jsf ... but beside that I would recommend to stay pattern .xhtml for the mapping mapping

Comment: how i have to save still i couldnt get the idea.... i am new in jsf.. please help me through ....

Comment: login.jsf like this only i have stored but when i run the project its automaticaly changed login.jsp thats way i am getting struggle